# Emulating phone screen size

Tags: google-chrome

A user has complained on how my website looks on his phone. His phone size is 4.5" with a resolution of 1280x768.

Is there any extension or setting I could use to see how the website looks on a 4.5" screen?

Comment: If you expect to have a large number of "mobile" users, you should probably create a mobile friendly version of your site.

Comment: I don't know about Chrome but in Firefox it's very easy to test responsive design with the [built-in tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode). You can set to any resolution required

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you might like to try [www.browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com) which allows you to test external and internal site on a variety of platforms, devices, browsers and resolutions.

I'm in no way connected to browser stack btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resolution test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal) in Chrome to test various resolutions:

> An extension for developers to test web pages in different screen resolutions, with an option to define your own resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Responsive design testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) support is now available on Chrome. Just open [device mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) and choose your needed resolution

[image: device mode]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/imgs/device-mode-initial-view.png))</sub>